# Retrieving json data with jquery in html local file

Tags: html, json, codeigniter

i need help ! i want to retrieve json data from a Codeigniter server.
This is my html local file (d://myproject/index.html)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : serverUrl+'mobcontroller/users/',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    data : $("#formlogin").serialize(),
    dataType : MobileJsonType[1],
    beforeSend : function(){//do stuff here},
    success : function(responseData) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // do stuff here    
    },
    complete: function(xhr, settings){
        alert(JSON.stringify(xhr)+'\n'+settings);
    }
 });
```

and codeigniter controller look like this

```
public function index()
{
    $type_message = 'success';
    $message = 'Mobile plateform';
    $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    $this->output->set_status_header(200);
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->_display();
    echo json_encode( array('type_message' => $type_message, 'message' => $message) );
}
```

i obtain json data response with the js error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Please help me!

Comment: Try this, success : function(responseData) { alert(responseData.type_message);}. Assumed MobileJsonType[1] value `json`

Answer (score 0):

Change your success function to

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

and let us know what the output is.

I'm unfamiliar with codeigniter but is it possible that $this->output->_display(); echos something which the JS is trying to parse? If you place

```
ob_clean();
```

above your

```
 echo json_encode(...
```

it will clear the buffer which was going to be sent back to the JS, and that way only your encoded JSON will go back which the JS can parse.

Answer (score 0):

You ajax request should be something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : serverUrl+'mobcontroller/users/',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    data : $("#formlogin").serialize(),
    beforeSend : function(){//do stuff here},
    success : function(responseData) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // do stuff here    
    },
    complete: function(xhr, settings){
        alert(JSON.stringify(xhr)+'\n'+settings);
    }
 });
```

I have removed propertydata `dataType : MobileJsonType[1]`
Also you dont need to use `JSON.stringify`. 
The returned result is already json due to php's `json_encode`

And the error you are facing is due to `beforeSend` because `beforeSend` first hits the server to check if the request is allowed or not. if it sends true the actual request will proceed otherwise you need to handle it yourself. I assume you need to send some token with serialized data. Hope it helps. if you remove property `beforeSend` the request will work fine i think.